# Azure Artifacts - where to find vstsFeed and vstsFeedPackage to set values of UniversalPackages task

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am using Azure DevOps UniversalPackages@0 task to download from an Azure Artifacts feed. I am using [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/universal-packages-v0?view=azure-pipelines) to set the values of UniversalPackages@0 task. By looking into my Azure DevOps project artifactory, no where can I find the two arguments vstsFeed and vstsFeedPackage. These values are mandatory for the task:

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Download Artifact with Universal Packages'
  inputs:
    vstsFeed: '****'
    vstsFeedPackage: '****'
    vstsPackageVersion: 0.8.4
```

**Please note that I know by using classic editor and using universal packages task I can generate the yaml file. But that's not what I want. I want to know how via DevOps API or from the DevOps portal I can find these two values and put them in the above code.**

Here is what I see when I check my feed in Azure Artifacts. As you see no where these values (**vstsFeed** and **vstsFeedPackage**) are mentioned.

[image: Azure Artifacts Feed]

Comment: The feature is called Azure Artifacts. Artifactory is a completely different product. Please be sure you use the right terminology, otherwise it's likely to confuse people.

Answer (score 2):

> Instead it is something like: vstsFeed: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001'

This vstsFeed is composed of projectid and feed id. For example: `vstsFeed: Projectid/Feedid`

To get the Vsts feed id and the package id, you can use Rest API: [Artifact Details - Get Packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-packages?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)

```
GET https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/packages?api-version=7.0
```

In the Response, you can get the project id , feedid and package id.

[image]

The task also supports defining feed name  and package name.

For example:

```
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Download Artifact with Universal Packages'
  inputs:
    vstsFeed: 'projectname/feedname'
    vstsFeedPackage: 'package'
    vstsPackageVersion: 0.8.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return one level to Artifacts view. Then, in the drop down menu, there is Artifact feed name (vstsFeed), and below there are Artifact feed packages (vstsFeedPackage - in your case "py_dataenginee..." without semantic version at the end).

More details in picture [image]

According to the documentation, the values in your screenshot are named differently, but still able to pair them according the documentation:

- vstsFeed - Feed
- vstsFeedPackage - Package name

source https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/universal-packages-v0?view=azure-pipelines

I've added notes to your screenshot.

[image]

Comment: The link you shared is exactly the one I was looking into. Let me clarify more. The vsts feed needs to be some alphanuumeric value and not the name of the feed. If you put the name of the feed it will fail. Instead it is something like:

vstsFeed: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001'

The same link suggested using classic editor to have it generate the yaml. I want to know where to find this alphanumeric value for vstsFeed without using the classic editor capabilities.

Comment: kevin has answered that in his anwer